# FTP Protocol rename wait move before answer or no

Tags: ftp, sftp

I'm trying to figure out if a SFTP (Secure File Transfert Protocol)/ FTP (File Transfert Protocol) server is returning an answer from the 'rename' cmd to the client before/while he moves the file or after he moved it.

I tryed to take a look to this RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959

But I find the information nowhere.

By example, could this happend ? :

```js
string[] files = sftp.list('/in'); // ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
sftp.rename('/in/' + files[0]);
sftp.list('/in');                  // ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
sleep(1000);
sftp.list('/in');                  // ['file2.txt']
```

Edit: Looks like the answer is sending on the synchronous way just after that the file finished to move.

Comment: FTP and SFTP are completely unrelated protocols. It makes no sense to ask one question for both. Which protocol are you using?

Comment: I'm not speaking about "Simple File Transfert Protocol" either.  I was referring to all the mentions on "FTP" in your question.

Comment: Anyway, SFTP server responds to `SSH_FXP_RENAME` request only after actually renaming the file. Though I'm not sure if this is what you ask for. This question looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578).